# Gradle behaving differently using ZFS

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle, solaris-10, zfs

I have run into an interesting issue with gradle. When running

```
gradle test
```

On a Solaris 10, with sparc architecture, and a mounted ZFS (zpool) filesystem, I get Mockito errors that it can't verify the mock in my java project. This does not happen when running the tests on my windows machine.

After experimenting using a UFS formatted partition, the problem goes away and all the tests pass.

My question is, does Gradle not support ZFS, or is there some configuration I need to change in Gradle to ensure tests will run smoothly? This is very important for us since our continuous integration server (Jenkins) uses a ZFS for its workspace.

Comment: Please show us the actual error messages and stack traces.

Comment: I can't. Work policies prohibit me from transferring data to this computer